# Concatenate Series using For

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm having some trouble creating a DataFrame with some Series. Is there a way to concat them with a for? Because each time I try I only get the last Series in the DF, when I really want it to concat it the columns and not in place.

```
suma_queries = list()
for query in queries:
    cur.execute(query)
    schema = lib.get_schema_sql(cursor = cur)
    table = lib.get_table_sql(cur)  
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = table, columns = schema)
    suma_queries.append(df.iloc[:,18].sum())

suma_queries = pd.Series(suma_queries)
concat_df = pd.concat([suma_queries], axis=1)
```

As you see, for each "suma_queries" Series gotten from the for, I try to concatenate it to a dataframe called concat_df, and so on for the next "suma_queries" Series, but in the end, I only get the last Series, because the for replaces the value.

What I want at the end should be a dataframe like:

```
Series1      Series2    Series3 …   SeriesN
s1_1         s2_1       s3_1        sn_1
s1_2         …          …           …
s1_3         …          …           …
…            …          …           …
s1_n         s2_n       s3_n        sn_n
```

where each column is a series.

Please let me know if there is way to do it,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you should reasign the appended dataframe back to itself in the for loop:

```
for query in queries:
    cur.execute(query)
    schema = lib.get_schema_sql(cursor = cur)
    table = lib.get_table_sql(cur)  
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = table, columns = schema)
    suma_queries=suma_queries.append(df.iloc[:,18].sum())

suma_queries = pd.Series(suma_queries)
concat_df = pd.concat([suma_queries], axis=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: that's because suma_queries is not declared before that asignation and thus doesn't have a type.

Comment: It is declared as a list at the beginning of the for, sorry, I typed wrong.

Comment: Maybe declare it as a dataframe instead?